# Run two functions at the same time in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, sigpipe

This is a simple code for multi threading in python.

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=f1, args=('f1')) 
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=f2, args=('f2')) 

p1.start() 
# starting process 2 
p2.start() 

# wait until process 1 is finished 
p1.join() 
# wait until process 2 is finished 
p2.join()
```

But after running the code I'm getting the following error:

> BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

I searched SO and other sites and the common answer was to include the following snippet:

```
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL)
```

But when I run this, I'm getting the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'SIGPIPE' from 'signal' (C:\Users\u65988\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\signal.py)

I tried checking all solutions, but none of them is working out! Please help me out on this!

For reference both functions:

```
def f1 (string):
          print(string)

def f2 (string):
          print(string)
```

Comment: (1) This is multiprocessing, not multithreading. (2) How are f1 and f2 defined? (3) You have to use `if __name__ == "__main__"` on Windows (see docs)

Comment: Well the error says a problem with `signal`, on mac these imports run just fine. On windows seems to be a problem with this package, check this [issue](https://github.com/dedupeio/csvdedupe/issues/51)

Comment: How are you running your code?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I tried (3), but its still showing the same error. 
 Siddhant: I tried the solutions for that issue, still not working.
 Stovfl: For me it threw the error and I tried looking for solutions and the common solution written everywhere was to add those lines, that's why I tried adding it. 
AdamGold:  I'm running the code on Spyder using Anaconda. The execution starts from " if __name__==__main__". I just tried a basic code to know if multiprocessing is working out. But unfortunately this error does not seem to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main.py/script you wish to run, you have to write

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    start_process_1()

    start_process_2()


    join_process_1()

    join_process_2()
```

This is an error specific to Windows platforms, and is solved accordingly if the function calls are wrapped/put inside the `if__name__ == "__main__"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The code is now running! But still the statements inside the print are not printing. Can you let me know why that's happening?

Comment: You can provide me the code and I will have a look on it.